# How to map an IList<T> to a Bitmap?

Tags: c#, linq

IList contains a set of z samples on an xy plane (all doubles).
`GetColor()` converts any z to a pixel color.
I plan to scale the the IList x and y limits to correspond to the bitmap width and height since the number of samples is generally not equal to the number of pixels.
Samples is collected as a raster scan so the order is different. I don't know how many samples till the scan is complete.
Is there a clever way to use LINQ and/or a Lambda Expression to find the closest IList x and y for each bitmap pixel?

```
PictureBox pb;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pb.Width, pb.Height);
IList<Sample> samples = new List<Sample>();
// ... collect samples ...
// Find closest sample
Sample GetSample(int w, int h)
{
    // how to find closest x and y for each w and h?
}
// Map samples to bitmap
for (var w = 0; w < pb.Width; w++) 
{
    for (var h = 0; h < pb.Height; h++)
    {
        var sample = GetSample(w, h);
        var color = GetColor(sample.z, samples.Min().z, samples.Max().z);
        bmp.SetPixel(w, h, color);
    }
}
pb.Image = bmp;
Color GetColor(double z, double minZ, double maxZ)
{
    var red = (int) (255*(z - minZ)/(maxZ - minZ));
    var blue = 255 - red;
    var green = red*blue/65;
    return Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
}
// class Sample
public class Sample : IComparable<Sample>
{
    public double z { get; set; }
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
    int IComparable<Sample>.CompareTo(Sample s)
    {
        return z < s.z ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps method I've provided would help you, it allows find closest number.

The problem to find the closest Sample is to deal in cases when you have:

```
w == 1
h == 1

Sample(x = 1, y = 8)
Sample(x = 8, x = 1)

Which one should be considered as closest?
```

**Usage:**

```
int closestX = this.FindClosest(samples.Select(p => p.x).ToList(), w);
int closestY = this.FindClosest(samples.Select(p => p.y).ToList(), h);
```

**Method:**

```
public int FindClosest(IList<int> points, int desiredNumber)
{
    int nearest = -1;
    int latestDistance = int.MaxValue;

    foreach (int t in points)
    {
        if (t == desiredNumber)
        {
            return t;
        }

        int currentDistance = Math.Abs(desiredNumber - t);
        if (currentDistance < latestDistance) 
        {                    
            nearest = t;
            latestDistance = currentDistance;
        }
    }

    return nearest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that a lambda is just a function, and Linq is mostly just looping over collections applying functions to the contents. There will be no magic optimisation happening.

It looks like you're asking how to fill in the body of this function:

```
Sample GetSample(int w, int h)
{
    // how to find closest x and y for each w and h?
}
```

And the implementation should examine the contents of the `IList<Sample> samples`. How would you write that as plain looping code?

It may be that you could optimise it by using a better data structure than a plain `IList`. Depends on what you need to do when searching `samples`.